# Regular expression to remove quotations

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regular expression to satisfy these requirements ? I can only use a string.replaceAll function ..

a)     For `&rdquo;` which appears at end of paragraph which has a `&ldquo;`, but not `&ldquo; &ldquo;`—remove `&rdquo;`

b)    For `&ldquo;` which appears at beginning of paragraph remove  `&ldquo;`  [NOTE: If there is `&ldquo; &ldquo;`, it should now be `&ldquo;`]

c)     For `&rdquo;` which appears at end of paragraph without a matching `&ldquo;` at beginning of paragraph –remove `&rdquo;`

EDIT:

```
Rule a)
Transform:
String input1 ="&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="&ldquo;remove quotes"

Don't change anything:
String input1 ="&ldquo;&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="&ldquo;&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;"

Rule b)
Transform:
String input1 ="&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="remove quotes&rdquo;"

Replace with single ldquo:
String input1 ="&ldquo;&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="&ldquo;remove quotes&rdquo;"

Rule c)
Do nothing (there is a matching ldquo):
String input1 ="&ldquo;do not remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="&ldquo;do not remove quotes&rdquo;"

Transform(no matching ldquo hence remove rdquo):
String input1 ="remove quotes&rdquo;" 
String output1 ="remove quotes"

I think I am going to run all the 3 rules separately on the string. What would be 3 regexes and replace expressions ?
```

Comment: You can only use one string.replaceAll call, or multiple?

Comment: How do I do it in one call ? and in 3 separate calls ?

Comment: Are these tags ever nested? and can you provide some sample text to cover all your cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Description

This regex will do the following:

1. if 2 initial `&ldquo;` strings and a ending `&rdquo;`, then remove single `&ldquo;`
2. if 1 initial `&ldquo;` string and a ending `&rdquo;`, then remove nothing
3. if 0 initial `&ldquo;` strings and a ending `&rdquo;`, then remove ending `&rdquo;`

regex: `^(?=.*?&rdquo;)&ldquo;\s*(&ldquo;)|^(?=.*?&rdquo;)(&ldquo;.*?&rdquo;)|^(?!&ldquo;)(.*?)&rdquo;`

replace with: `$1$2$3`

[image]

Input text

```
&ldquo; DO NOTHING  &rdquo;
&ldquo; &ldquo; REMOVE INITIAL LD  &rdquo;
REMOVE RD  &rdquo;
```

Output text respecitivly

```
&ldquo; DO NOTHING  &rdquo;
&ldquo; REMOVE INITIAL LD &rdquo;
REMOVE RD
```

---

These expressions where hashed out from a chat session, and written to be executed one at a time in A,B,C order, however because they are seperate, they can be executed in any order the developer would like which would change based on the desired output.

A

- 1 LD and 1 RD, remove the RD
- 2 LD and 1 RD, do nothing
- regex: `^(&ldquo;(?!\s*&ldquo;).*?)&rdquo;`
- replace with `$1`

B

- 1 LD, remove 1 LD
- 2 LD, remove 1 LD
- regex: `^&ldquo;(\s*(?:&ldquo;)?)`
- replace with `$1`

C

- 1 LD and 1 RD, do nothing
- 0 LD and 1 RD, remove the RD
- regex: `^(?!&ldquo;)(.*?)&rdquo;`
- replace with `$1`

Comment: Hey Cam, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: Denomales, The first rule is only remove &rdquo if there is a single &ldquo; and not &ldquo;&ldquo;

Comment: see update, if the string starts with a single `&ldquo;` and ends with `&rdquo;` then leave as is.

Comment: The first rule would be to remove &rdquo; if there is a single &ldquo; and to leave &rdquo; as is if there is a &ldquo;&ldquo;

Comment: The 2nd rule you have written is actually the first rule, and it should be "if 1 initial &ldquo; string and a ending &rdquo; then remove &rdquo; unless the string begins with &ldquo;&ldquo; in which case you would do nothing" .. I have 2 run all the 3 rules sequentially

Comment: My expression actually does that in reverse by design so that it catches a  `&ldquo;&ldquo;` followed by a `&rdquo;` instead of accidentally seeing the the first of two `&ldquo;` and handling that as if it where a single `&ldquo;`. It sounds like you're trying to express four very different rules but combining them to be three rules. Can you please expand your sample text and desired outputs so show each case?

Comment: Denomales, does it make sense now ?

Comment: So you're going to issue each of these instructions against your stings? In what order are you going to issue these instructions?

Comment: In order a) b) c) mentioned above.

Comment: Rule B's don't change anything actually has a change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31882/discussion-between-phoenix-and-denomales)

Comment: Denomales, This doesn't work: String quotes2="&ldquo;<ceqbwpt/>Continuing education courses<ceqewpt/>&rdquo; means courses approved by the [<centd>or continuing medical education courses that serve to improve patient safety and to maintain quality national standards in the prevention of medical errors</centd>].&rdquo;"; 

quotesPattern1 = Pattern.compile("^(?!&ldquo;)(.*?)&rdquo;$", Pattern.MULTILINE); 

System.out.println(quotesPattern1.matcher(quotes2).replaceAll("$1"));
Here the ldquo matches rdquo in the middle and the rdquo does not have a matching ldquo in the beginning

Comment: I give up. This problem has gone well beyond the question format endorsed by StackOverflow and is now we are neck deep in code writing.
My frustration here comes from the fact that your initial question is a moving target. Each time we have a solution which meets your criteria, you present additional "new" edge cases which where not considered when you defined the rules. 

To resolve this issue you'll need to more thoroughly describe the problem, collect all possible edge cases and post it as a new question or hire a developer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, strings like:

```
&ldquo; Criteria 1, ending with RD and beginning with LD, but not LDLD, remove RD &rdquo;
&ldquo; &ldquo; Criteria 1, ending with RD but beginning with LDLD, do nothing to RD &rdquo;
&ldquo; &ldquo; Criteria 2, beginning with LDLD, make it begin with LD &rdquo;
Criteria 3 with non-matching RD, remove RD &rdquo;
```

To become:

```
&ldquo; Criteria 1, ending with RD and beginning with LD, but not LDLD, remove RD
&ldquo; Criteria 1, ending with RD but beginning with LDLD, do nothing to RD &rdquo;
&ldquo; Criteria 2, beginning with LDLD, make it begin with LD &rdquo;
Criteria 3 with non-matching RD, remove RD
```

You can use the regex:

```
^(?:(“(?! “).*?)\s*”|(“) “(.*)|((?!“).*?)\s*”)$
```

And replace with `$1$2$3$4`.

See how it works [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/fW9vZ5).

Or if you meant the symbols, you can find another similar one [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/rS3vS9).

```
“ Criteria 1, ending with RD and beginning with LD, but not LDLD, remove RD ”
“ “ Criteria 1, ending with RD but beginning with LDLD, do nothing to RD ”
“ “ Criteria 2, beginning with LDLD, make it begin with LD ”
Criteria 3 with non-matching RD, remove RD ”
```

Become:

```
“ Criteria 1, ending with RD and beginning with LD, but not LDLD, remove RD
“ Criteria 1, ending with RD but beginning with LDLD, do nothing to RD ”
“ Criteria 2, beginning with LDLD, make it begin with LD ”
Criteria 3 with non-matching RD, remove RD
```

And if you want the debuggex picture which might make the regex more understandable:

[image: Regular expression image]

Comment: Oh and the `\s*` I have put is just in case there are random spaces before the closing quote.